# Sorting an Queue based on Services Set (Service A, Service B, Service B,Service C )

Tags: sorting, queue, quicksort, advanced-queuing

i have a problem of sorting a Queue with aspect to service set , Queue contains elements types of 3 different Services (Service A, Service B, Service C), now i need to sort the Queue in the form of Services sets (A,B,B,C).
 Like an 
 array = { Service A,Service B,Service B,Service C,Service A,Service B,Service B,Service C,...}

i want to remove and add new elements in the same sequence ..

if an element is removed it should not replace the same type of element but it should bring up the element that placed next Like if i removed Service A result should be array =  { Service B,Service B,Service C,Service A,Service B,Service B,Service C,...}

the current issue is after sorting Queue once an element is removed from Queue it supposed to move to next element of the set but it bring up the same type of element that i removed

Comment: What is the issue, and what have you tried?

Comment: the current issue is after sorting Queue once an element is removed from Queue it supposed to move to next element of the set but it bring up the same  type of element that i removed

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You can edit your question to do that. At the moment, your question is not very clear, and it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: If the container is a queue, that would suggest using a bottom up merge sort (not quick sort) with 2 queues. The question doesn't specify how to compare two sets, are all 4 elements needed (A,B,B,C) for a compare, or just the first element (A)?

Comment: Thanks to all of you , i get solved this b using  Sequence and Series Formula

Comment: https://www.purplemath.com/modules/series2.htm    used the first formula